# Open window and get contents with JS equivalent to VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, xss

I have written a working application in VBA that opens a browser window in the background and gets the content of that browser windows for further processing. In order to make the experience more user friendly I'm trying to convert this to a webpage. However I cannot find a way to get the contents when I open the browserwindow in Javascript.

I have tried it with and Iframe and with window.open(..), but in both cases I run into the same-origin-policy.

Is there any way to realize this without users having to configure VBA? If so, can you give me any pointers?

If it's not possible in JS then I'm willing to pick up whatever other language. The delimiting factor is that I do not have access to the server the other page resides on. It's on my intranet, but I can't make any modifactions to it.

Comment: No, client side webpage can not do that. If you don't want VBA, and you still want script, a general approach would be to build a server and use server side language (e.g. [tag:PHP]) to fetch content.

Comment: Assuming you want to replace VBA with something simpler/lightweight HTAs ignore SOP; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: HTA look spromissing. Thanx, i'll look into it.